# Javascript - Quickly remove duplicates in object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, duplicates

I have 2 arrays with objects in them such as:

```
[{"Start": 1, "End": 2}, {"Start": 4, "End": 9}, {"Start": 12, "End": 16}, ... ]
```

I want to merge the 2 arrays while removing duplicates. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
array1.concat(array2);
```

Then I am doing a nested `$.each` loop, but as my arrays get larger and larger, this takes `O(n^2)` time to execute and is not scalable.

I presume there is a quicker way to do this, however, all of the examples I have found are working with strings or integers.

Any recommended algorithms or methods out there to make this faster?

Comment: Are they both ordered arrays?

Comment: They are not ordered arrays, but I could sort them if there is a way to make it faster via using 2 for loops with an incrementing index on each array.

Comment: You could get better performance by not using `$.each` as the array gets larger.

Comment: If the order does not matter, you are better of using objects `{}` then you could check the keys, which is just o(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer bases on the assumption that the order does not matter and you can create unique keys from your objects.

You copy all n entries from the array a to an object c, creating a unique key, after that you copy all m entries from array b to that object (this will automatically eliminate the duplicates) and you are finished in `O(n+m)`:

```
var a = [{"Start": 1, "End": 2}, {"Start": 4, "End": 9}];
var b = [{"Start": 4, "End": 9}, {"Start": 3, "End": 12}];

var c = {};
a.forEach(function(el){c[el.Start+".."+el.End] = el});
b.forEach(function(el){c[el.Start+".."+el.End] = el});

console.log(c);
// yields: {"1..2":{"Start": 1, "End": 2},"4..9":{"Start": 4, "End": 9},"3..12":{"Start": 3, "End": 12}}
```

This notation in this object is a bit redundant but you are extremely fast on merging the two arrays. Maybe this could be improved further.

Comment: This was super fast. I tried the other listed algorithms and this one performed the quickest.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the objects first, low to high. `O(n log n)` with quicksort.

Then you can make pruning algorithm that can take advantage of this sorting to loop through both arrays in one loop in `O(2n)`.

The merge the original array and the pruned array.

---

Keep in mind though that objects in JavaScript have no order, you can't sort them. Convert to an array, keep references and sort that.

Comment: Never heard of binary sort... do you mean quicksort? ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: Yes quicksort, I think this what most JavaScript implemenations use when you `Array.sort`

Comment: Using objects would be superior, you could merge and eliminate duplicates in o(n) since the lookup is only o(1).

Comment: Objects use a HashMap, so `O(log n)` for a lookup I believe. OPs objects don't have a hash (although arguably - looking at the data - you could create one). This isn't always feasible though.

Comment: Object Lookups are basically Dictionary lookups, using O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with javascript, so not 100% sure this is doable (not sure about subtlties of comparing objects for equality, etc), but in java or other languages, something like this might work:

- Iterate over first array.
- For each element store into a "counter" hashmap where key is the object and value is the count.

After this first pass, you should have something like:

```
{{"Start": 1, "End": 2}:1, {"Start": 4, "End": 9}:1, {"Start": 12, "End": 16}:1, ... }
```

- Then, iterate over the second array
- For each element, lookup current element inside counter hashmap.
- If the counter hashmap contains a key that matches the current element it's a duplicate
- Otherwise, append to the first array.

Might be a tad faster than having to sort first (if it's possible to use objects as keys, that is)?