# Remove duplicates from object array - Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to get _.uniq() working on the following structure:

```
[
    {'x' : 1, 'y': 2},
    {'x' : 1, 'y': 2},
    {'x' : 2, 'y': 3},
    {'x' : 2, 'y': 4},
    {'x' : 3, 'y': 4}
]
```

where the result should be:

```
[
    {'x' : 1, 'y': 2},
    {'x' : 2, 'y': 3},
    {'x' : 2, 'y': 4},
    {'x' : 3, 'y': 4}
]
```

ie duplicate items removed. I'd like to avoid stringify, because I then just have to parse each back out to a JSON object.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: tring Matt's solution below, I'm missing something I think - this doesn't work. If I log the values for a and b, I see

```
_.uniq($scope.validNotes, function (a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
    return a.x === b.x && a.y === b.y;
});


Object {x: 2, y: 3} 0 
Object {x: 1, y: 0} 1 
Object {x: 2, y: 3} 2 
Object {x: 3, y: 2} 3 
Object {x: 4, y: 2} 4
Object {x: 5, y: 1} 5
```

Which obviously means I'll never find any dupes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - Quickly remove duplicates in object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650626/javascript-quickly-remove-duplicates-in-object-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate objects with Underscore for Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923890/removing-duplicate-objects-with-underscore-for-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because two objects are not `==` or `===`, just because they have the same keys, you will need to use the [`[iterator]` argument of the `uniq()` function](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq);

```
_.uniq(myArray, function (item) {
    return item.x + item.y;
});
```

Note you'll need to return a unique string combination; consider the case of `{ x: 11, y: 1 }` and `{ x: 1, y: 11 }`; my code will resolve both to `111`, and treat them as the same.

Something like:

```
_.uniq(myArray, function (item) {
    return 'x:' + item.x + 'y:' + item.y;
});
```

... would be more resilient, but it depends on the values of your data, of course.

Comment: @Nathan: Eugh, sorry... noobed the arguments of the iterator. Try now?

Comment: awesome, thanks. Wasn't sure how the iterator worked, makes sense now. Works even better once I realised my data was incorrect too

Answer (score 0):

If you have abstract data structure in your JSON, it will be better to compare array elements one bt one like strings, using stringify. Because you have new object in every array element, every literal object notation ie `{}` creates new object in javascript language and it's doesn't metter has it the same properties or not.

But, if you have stucture like x,y use [Matt answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906026/2525067)